# How to transform Table data to another Table format in SAS

Tags: sas

I am stuck in transforming the data table from one format to another format using the SAS Programming function. The structure of the Table is given as below:

```
id  Date        Time    assigned_pat_loc    prior_pat_loc       Activity
1   May/31/11   8:00    EIAB^EIAB^6                             Admission
1   May/31/11   9:00    8w^201               EIAB^EIAB^6      Transfer to 8w
1   Jun/8/11    15:00   8w^201                                  Discharge
2   May/31/11   5:00    EIAB^EIAB^4                             Admission 
2   May/31/11   7:00    10E^45               EIAB^EIAB^4    Transfer to 10E
2   Jun/1/11    1:00    8w^201                  10E^45      Transfer to 8w
2   Jun/1/11    8:00    8w^201                                 Discharge
3   May/31/11   9:00    EIAB^EIAB^2                            Admission
3   Jun/1/11    9:00    8w^201               EIAB^EIAB^2    Transfer to 8w
3   Jun/5/11    9:00    8w^201                                 Discharge
4   May/31/11   9:00    EIAB^EIAB^9                           Admission
4   May/31/11   7:00    10E^45               EIAB^EIAB^9    Transfer to 10E
4   Jun/1/11    8:00    10E^45                                     Death
```

[image: 1]

- “Id” is the randomly generated patient identifier.
- “Date” and “Time” is the timestamp of the event.
- “Assigned_pat_loc” is the current patient location in the hospital, formatted as “unit^room^bed”. EIAB is the internal code for the emergency department, with most of the admissions process through the emergency department.
- "Prior_pat_loc” is the location where the patient was immediately prior to the current location.
- “Activity” is the description of the event. It includes entries like “Admission”, “Transfer to” “Transfer from” “Discharge”, and “Death”.
- You will notice a lot of duplicate records, where the same transfer is recorded in both the departing and the receiving unit. You will be able to tell by looking at the time stamp – they are identical for duplicate records.

I want to transform it into the following table.
[image]

Here are the details of the variables.

- r_id is the name of the variable you will generate for the id of the other patient.
- patient 1 had two room-sharing episodes, both in 8w^201 (room 201 of unit 8w); he shared the room with patient 2 for 7 hours (1 am to 8 am on June 1) and with patient 3 for 96 hours (9 am on June 1 to 9 am on June 5).
- Patient 2 also had two-room sharing episodes. The first one was with patient 4 in 10E^45 (room 45 of unit 10E) and lasted 18 hours (7 am May 31 to 1 am June 1); the second one is the 7-hour episode with patient 1 in 8w^201.
- Patient 3 had only one room-sharing episode with patient 1 in room 8w^201, lasting 96 hours.
- Patient 4, also, had only one room-sharing episode, with patient 2 in room 10E^45, lasting 18 hours.
- *Note that the room-sharing episodes are listed twice, once for each patient.*

Please anyone guide me how it could be done?

Comment: Removed references to Stata. Question does not even mention Stata.

Comment: Are the DATE and TIME variables actual date and time variables?  Or are they just strings like in your display? Your discharge records seem to have the room id in the wrong column.  It should be in the prior column.

Comment: Do not post data as photographs.  It is impossible to code from photograhs.  Please show what SAS code you have attempted so far to do this.

Comment: @Tom Yes, these are actual date and time.

Comment: @Tom bro, I have no code, I tried it using SAS Modular but it does not work. It is calculating correlation which is not correct.I need to find the second table using SAS Programmer. Is it make sense?

Comment: @Shakeel you have no programs that you've tried writing to produce the desired results? Have you written any SAS programs before?

Comment: @StuSztukowski No bro

Comment: @StuSztukowski do you know to do this?

Comment: Why does output for `2` and `4` show a start time of `7:00` when id `4` entered room `10E` at `9:00` ?

Answer (score 0):

We need to process the data by location

```
proc sort HAVE;
  by assigned_pat_loc data time;
run;
```

In the result, we don not need temporary variables (starting with underscore) and the date and time must be renamed to end_date and end_time.

```
data WANT (drop= _: rename=(date=end_date time=end_time));
  set HAVE;
  by assigned_pat_loc data time;
```

I generalize the problem to rooms with a capacity above 2 and use arrays.
Extending the temporary arrays beyond &max_patients, saves me a few if-statements.
Note that temporary arrays are dropped in the result and are retained anyway.

```
  %let max_patients = 9;
  array id_r {&max_patients - 1} id_1 - id_%eval(&max_patients - 1); 
  array patients temporary {&max_patients + 1}; 
  array admissions temporary {&max_patients + 1}; 
  if _N_ eq 1 then patient_count = 0;
  retain patient_count;
```

for every pat_loc, start all over

```
  if first.assigned_pat_loc then do;
    do patient_nr = 1 to patient_count;
      patients[patient_nr] = .;
    end;
    patient_count = 0;
  end;
```

if a patient leaves, calculate the time she spent

```
  if Activity in (“Discharge”, “Death”) then do;
    _found_patient = 0;
    do _patient_nr = 1 to patient_count;
      if patients[_patient_nr] eq id then do;
        start_date = datepart(admissions[_patient_nr]);
        start_time = timepart(admissions[_patient_nr]);
        duration = (dhms(date,0,0,time) - admissions[_patient_nr]) / 3600;
        _found_patient = 1;
      end;
    end;
```

shift the patients that arrived later

```
    if _found_patient then do;
      patients[_patient_nr] = patients[_patient_nr + 1];
      admissions[_patient_nr] = admissions[_patient_nr + 1];
    end;
    patient_count = patient_count - 1;
```

find out who else was in the pat_loc and write the result

```
    do _patient_nr = 1 to patient_count;
      id_r[_patient_nr] = patents[_patient_nr];
    end;
    output;
  end;
```

if a patient arrives, register that for later

```
  else do;
    patient_count = patient_count + 1;
    patients[_patient_nr] = id;
    admissions[_patient_nr] = dhms(date,0,0,time); 
  end;
run;
```

sort the results

```
proc sort;
  by id start_date start_time;
run;
```

*Disclaimer: this is a draft, which might need debugging.*

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with ranges in which there is a possibility of an unexpected overlap case you can enumerate over the range and perform simpler logic for finding shared time/unit/room.

Example:

```
data have;

length id date time 8 loc ploc $20 activity $10;
input 
id  Date& date11.   Time time5.   loc    ploc       Activity;
format date date9. time time5.;

datetime = dhms (date,0,0,0) + time;

length unit room bed punit proom pbed $4;

unit = scan(loc,1,'^');
room = scan(loc,2,'^');
bed  = scan(loc,3,'^');

punit = scan(ploc,1,'^');
proom = scan(ploc,2,'^');
pbed  = scan(ploc,3,'^');

drop loc ploc;

datalines;
1   31-May-2011   8:00    EIAB^EIAB^6          .                Admission
1   31-May-2011   9:00    8w^201               EIAB^EIAB^6      Transfer to 8w
1    8-Jun-2011  15:00    8w^201               .                Discharge
2   31-May-2011   5:00    EIAB^EIAB^4          .                Admission 
2   31-May-2011   7:00    10E^45               EIAB^EIAB^4      Transfer to 10E
2    1-Jun-2011   1:00    8w^201               10E^45           Transfer to 8w
2    1-Jun-2011   8:00    8w^201               .                Discharge
3   31-May-2011   9:00    EIAB^EIAB^2          .                Admission
3    1-Jun-2011   9:00    8w^201               EIAB^EIAB^2      Transfer to 8w
3    5-Jun-2011   9:00    8w^201               .                Discharge
4   31-May-2011   9:00    EIAB^EIAB^9          .                Admission
4   31-May-2011   7:00    10E^45               EIAB^EIAB^9      Transfer to 10E
4    1-Jun-2011   8:00    10E^45               .                Death
;


* Fill in the ranges to get data by hour;

data hours(keep=id in_unit in_room at_dt);
  set have;
  by id;

  retain at_dt in_unit in_room;

  if first.id then do;
    at_dt = datetime;
    in_unit = unit;
    in_room = room;
  end;
  else do;
    do at_dt = at_dt to datetime-1 by dhms(0,1,0,0);
      output;
    end;
    in_unit = unit;
    in_room = room;
  end;

  format at_dt datetime16.;
run;

* prepare for transposition;

proc sort data=hours;
  by at_dt in_unit in_room id;
run;

* transpose to know which time/unit/room has multiple patients;

proc transpose data=hours out=roomies_by_hour(drop=_name_ where=(not missing(patid2))) prefix=patid;
  by at_dt in_unit in_room ;
  var id;
run;

* 'unfill' the individual hours to get ranges again;

data roomies;
  set roomies_by_hour;
  by in_unit in_room patid1 patid2;

  retain start_dt end_dt;
  format start_dt end_dt datetime16.;

  if first.patid2 then
    start_dt = at_dt;

  if last.patid2 then do;
    end_dt = at_dt;
    length_hrs = intck('hours', start_dt, end_dt);
    output;
  end;
run;

* stack data flipping perspective of who shared with who;

data roomies_mirrored;
  set 
    roomies                                         /* patid1 centric */
    roomies(rename=(patid1=patid2 patid2=patid1))   /* patid2 centric */
  ;
run;

proc sort data=roomies_mirrored;
  by patid1 start_dt;
run;
```